# resolve dependencies in package org.geoserver.wcs.kvp

Tags: java, geoserver

I try to run a Start.java in package org.geoserver.web 
 with following configuration :

JRE version : 1.8 
GeoServer version : master (2.10-beta) 
IDE : InteliJ IDEA 
mavan: Bundled (Mavan 3) (plugin of InteliJ IDEA

but seams it cannot find the classes from 
 `import org.geoserver.wcs.kvp` 
like 
 `import org.geoserver.wcs.kvp.rangesubset.ASTAxisId.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That (and other) classes are generated by javacc as part of the build for the WCS1_1 module.

In my local copy of the jar they are present:

```
jar tvf target/gs-wcs1_1-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep ASTA
  1057 Thu Oct 06 08:43:24 BST 2016 org/geoserver/wcs/kvp/rangesubset/ASTAxisId.class
  1073 Thu Oct 06 08:43:24 BST 2016 org/geoserver/wcs/kvp/rangesubset/ASTAxisSubset.class
```

and the source can be found in `target/generated-sources/javacc` so you may need to add that to the build path in InteliJ.

Comment: thanks, actually I could not find this class from  <code>target/generated-sources/javacc</code> but I find the jar file in the [link](http://build.geo-solutions.it/jenkins/job/GeoServer-Backup-Restore-Master/org.geoserver$gs-wcs1_1/59/) now at leas I can run it one time.

Comment: you would need to run mvn install in that module to create the target dir

Comment: the problem was I had a wrong version of the maven , geoserver need more than 3.1.1 to can successfully run this command, mvn clean install